# Two divs: the first one is floated and the position of the second one depends on its width, why?

Tags: css

I have two `divs`. The first one is `width: 50%` and the second on is `width: 80%`. When I set `float: left` to the first one, the text of the second one is placed on the right of the first one. That's ok, it is what I expect. See the code here:

```html
<div style="float: left; width: 50%; background: orange">floated div</div> 
<div style="width: 80%; background: red">second div</div>
```

**The doubt**: if I set `width: 30%` to the second div. The div is placed below the first one, why? Check the snippet:

```html
      <div style="float: left; width: 50%; background: orange">floated div</div> 
      <div style="width: 30%; background: red">second div</div>
```

Comment: If you set the width to "60%" in the code snippet you will begin to see why...

Answer (score 0):

`float` doesn't cause block elements to display side by side or wrap necessarily. Using `float` will cause *text and inline elements* that come after the floated element to wrap around it. So if the second div is wider than the first, the *text* in the second will wrap around the first. If the second div is more narrow (or the same size) as the first, it won't wrap since the second div is not just text or an inline element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

> The float CSS property specifies that an element should be taken from the normal flow and placed along the left or right side of its container, where text and inline elements will wrap around it.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, the first div is floated and therefore removed from the flow of the document. The second div then occupies the space behind the first div and since there just happens to be enough room for the text you've given in the second div, it all stays neatly on the same line. If you add a lot of text to your second div, you'll see that it will overflow and begin to wrap under the first div.

In your second example, again the first div is floated and removed from the flow of the document. Now however, since you only have the second div a width of 30%, there's not enough room for the text that it contains to exist on the same line since it's very narrow, so the text is forced below the text of the first div. If you remove the text from the second div, it will essentially disappear beneath the floated first div.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do with the snippet, but I would just add a clear between the 2 div's.

```html
<div style="float: left; width: 50%; background: orange">floated div</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div style="width: 80%; background: red">second div</div>
```